# How to create a field and an action on field in Plone 5?

Tags: plone, content-type

I have installed a Plone with the following information:

Plone vr 5.0.7 (5017)
CMF 2.2.10
Zope 2.13.26
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 26 2017, 16:31:12) [GCC 4.3.0] PIL 1.1.7

Was wondering how can I relate a field (when you add a field on content type) to an action!
So the idea is to create a field that admin can choose which user group can receive an email/notification when the content is published. I know I can add a rule content for emailing but I would have a choice to choose which user group can receive it. Could be an add-on or something in Plone?

Thank you!

Comment: For best results, please post Plone questions on our forum at https://community.plone.org

Answer (score 1):

Add a "User's group" condition in the content rule declaration.

Comment: Thanks! How would the user be able to choose which group(s) the notification is sent to? When new content is published, I am trying to offer the user (mostly admin) a choice regarding which group(s) notifications are sent to. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oh, it's more complicated than I thought, but there's a solution. The overall idea is this: you need to define a new string interpolation variable. They are the variables that are used in the email action content rule. You can use the variable in the To email field. You can write an adapter that defines this variable and use the request to extract the proper value. You'll need to decide how to expose this functionality in the interface. Almost exact same usecase (with a message instead of group) is here: https://github.com/eea/eea.climateadapt.plone/blob/master/eea/climateadapt/workflow.py#L41

Answer (score 1):

To actually add a field and relate it to an action, you'd need to program dedicated content-types.

Yet, as you want to grant the privilege "get mail on publication" to certain groups, it would be consistent to solve this as a permission-assignments, meaning to grant the groups a local-role on the item.

In concrete that would boil down to these steps:

- Create a new role, e.g. "Receiver".
- Install "collective.contentrules.mailtorole".
- Create a global content-rule which checks on publication of any item who holds the local-role "Receiver" on the item, and sends the mail to them.

The admin can then assign the groups to the new role "Receiver" via the sharing-tab of an item.